# Domain name not showing up in DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

It's been couple of days that I transferred my domain name from one AWS to another--dev environment to production. The problem is, the domain name isn't showing up in any DNS (Amazon or Google). I'm pretty sure I've configured the hosted zone correctly.

I'm also trying to verify SES which is failing and I also set MX records (Gmail) which don't work. The MX records and SES were set couple of days ago. Additionally, I created an A record to point to a elastic load balancer DNS name.

Any suggestions on what might be the problem? It's been couple of days and from past StackOverflow posts as well as past experience, DNS propagation on Amazon's server doesn't take more than 15 minutes.

---

EDIT:

Here is a timeline of events which can provide more information:

1. I had a domain *abc.com* on AWS account *user1*
2. The domain was transfered to AWS account *user2*
3. As of right now, the following hosted zone is created on *user2*'s account: [image]
4. The one thing this record set is missing is a CNAME to the load balancer which I had setup when the domain belonged to *user1*. However my understanding is that an A record should be good enough and it was a mistake on my part.

I'm using Windows and so I've flushed my DNS. I've tried looking up using AWS's DNS servers and Google's DNS server and nothing.

```
C:\>nslookup abc.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find abc.com: Server failed
```

It's been a couple of days since the domain was transferred. MX records were something I setup immediately and so I haven't gotten an email. If the DNS doesn't have any clue about the domain name, something must be wrong.

NOTE: The domain name is obfuscated to *abc.com*.

Comment: You have provided no information whatsoever that would let someone give a more useful answer than "You probably missed doing something or did something wrong". If  you want help, say what you did (now you only say what you intended to do, which is _very_ different) or at the very least mention the name that you think is not working.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl See my edit. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: When you created the new hosted zone, 4 NS were assigned -- not the NS records, but the actual name servers visible in the Route 53 console when you select the zone from the list of hosted zones.  Did you update your domain registrar with these 4 new values?  They almost certainly are not the same as before.  Also, if you edited the 4 NS records, put them back the way they were.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you so much!!! You were correct. The NS in the hosted zone was not the same as in the console. I update the values and I'm seeing the domain come up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @michael-sqlbot, the name servers were different in the console and hosted zone. I updated the name servers to the NS of the hosted zone. I see DNS propagation.